# Gradle : :Could not find method main() for arguments" on setting outputDir in sourceSets

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Please find the script below to clean and build a project using gradle.

Everything was working fine until I added outputDir to the sourceSets in java block.

On commenting out the outputDir line, the gradle clean and build is successful, but the class files are generated in ''build/classes//main'' which I did not want. I wanted the class in directory ''build/classes//'' and not create the main folder and place the class files in that.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//Declarations
def projectName="SomeProject"
def projectDir="build//classes"

sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         srcDir 'src'
         outputDir = file("${projectDir}")
        }
      }
   }


dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'],dir: 'lib')
}


jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Foo'  
        attributes 'Class-Path': 'lib/com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.31.jar lib/commons-io-2.6.jar lib/commons-net-3.6.jar lib/javax.mail.jar lib/jsch-0.1.54.jar lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar lib/jxl-2.6.jar lib/ojdbc8.jar'
    }
    baseName = '${projectName}'
}
```

Also tried with `outputdir 'build//classes/` but the same error is occuring as

```
Could not find method main() for arguments [build_3eivce3rhjp4go01pnr2m3vvmq$_run_closure1_closure6@87800a] on root project 'SomeProject'.
```

Please suggest what am I missing. Seems some basic issue to me, but can't crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this documentation : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html

`outputDir` is a *property*, not a *method*, so you are not using the correct syntax to set the property value : use the following instead:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            outputDir = file("${projectName}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: you are using simple quote ' in `'${projectName}'` instead of double 
quote " : this cannot work as your variable `projectName` will not be evaluated.

Comment: Made the changes suggested by @M.Ricciuti (edited the existing code).
This time received error as:
`No such property: outputDir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet`

Comment: it seems you are using an old version of Gradle : this property `outputDir` is available since release 4.x